# how to Condition ststus data mysql update (delete,add,up) on bashscript?

Tags: mysql, bash

echo "Downloading Arvancloud IPs list..."
rm -rf ip.txt
curl https://www.arvancloud.ir/fa/ips.txt  >> ip.txt

for  IPLIST in `cat ip.txt`

do

## echo $IPLIST

DB_USER='root';
DB_PASSWD='';

DB_NAME='iplist';
TABLE='iplist';

#Collect Rank Information from flightaware.com
date=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")

status=up
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
INSERT INTO $TABLE (`id`, `IPLIST`, `status`, `DATE`) VALUES ( NULL, "$IPLIST", "$status", "$date");
EOF
done

echo "Downloading Arvancloud IPs list..."
rm -rf ip.txt
curl https://www.arvancloud.ir/fa/ips.txt  >> ip.txt

for  IPLIST in `cat ip.txt`

do

## echo $IPLIST

DB_USER='root';
DB_PASSWD='';

DB_NAME='iplist';
TABLE='iplist';

#Collect Rank Information from flightaware.com
date=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")

status=up
mysql --user=$DB_USER --password=$DB_PASSWD $DB_NAME << EOF
INSERT INTO $TABLE (`id`, `IPLIST`, `status`, `DATE`) VALUES ( NULL, "$IPLIST", "$status", "$date");
EOF
done

Comment: Your code is hard to read : please have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.